# Python classes as a collection of functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

So here's a very simplified version of the situation I'm currently facing.

I have a class. It does a lot of things, but the primary thing I'm concerned about is that each class member currently accepts a library of static functions and executes a list of commands using that library.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, commands, library, data):
        self.commands = commands
        self.library = library
        self.data = data

    def execute(self):
        for command in self.commands:
            result = getattr(self.library, command)(self)
            self.data[result[0]] = result[1]
```

I want to have the capability of switch out these libraries of functions. The current issue is that most of the libraries I am constructing share some core functions, with other functions being different or being overridden. Currently I am using a class to represent these libraries, since the natural inheritance of the class structure handles everything for me.

```
class Foo:
    static_variable = 4

    @staticmethod
    def method_a(foo):
        return 'z', foo.data['x'] + foo.data['y']

    @classmethod
    def method_b(cls, foo):
        return 'x', foo.data['x'] * cls.static_variable


class FooAlt1(Foo):
    @classmethod
    def method_b(foo):
        return 'y', cls.static_variable


class FooAlt2(FooAlt1):
    static_variable = 1
```

The following is an example of executed code. It's very simple, so it might not get my point across perfectly. The actual code that I am trying to build determines the commands to execute via user input, the data set to run on based on changing environment variables taken from a data base, and then has some logic to assign them to the proper library of functions that will be able to handle everything.

```
foo1 = Example(commands=['method_b', 'method_a'], library=Foo, data={'x': 3, 'y': 4})
foo2 = Example(commands=['method_b', 'method_a'], library=FooAlt1, data={'x': 3})
foo3 = Example(commands=['method_b', 'method_a'], library=FooAlt2, data={'x': 3})

foo1.execute()
foo2.execute()
foo3.execute()

print('RESULTS')
print('foo1: {}'.format(foo1.data))
print('foo2: {}'.format(foo2.data))
print('foo3: {}'.format(foo3.data))

# RESULTS
# foo1: {'z': 16, 'x': 12, 'y': 4}
# foo2: {'z': 15, 'x': 3, 'y': 12}
# foo3: {'z': 6, 'x': 3, 'y': 3}
```

This method works well for me, but it feels very un-pythonic, since I'm using classes mostly as a storage container for functions. However, I can't think of a good way to implement this without using classes. The class structure lets me update things easier (I only have to change one function and everything that inherits that function will also be affected), and lets me easily inherit functions if I am making an alternate library that extends or modifies an existing library.

Is there a better way to achieve the result that I want, or am I stuck using classes?

Comment: Would a module not be a more straightforward abstraction of a collection of functions? It's still an object you can pass around.

Comment: How does inheritance work with modules? If I wanted to make an alternative version of a module but still keep the old one around, is there an easy way to do something like "give me all twenty functions in this module, except I want to override this function with a different definition and change some of these static variables around".

Comment: `new_module` could start with `from old_module import *` then define replacements for those it needs to.

Comment: I don't think classes are unpythonic in this case. It is very readable and easy to maintain so why bother?